# Is it possible to unbox an object to more than one value type?

Tags: c#

I have read in CLR via C#:

> Unboxing is really just the operation of obtaining a pointer to the
>   raw value type (data fields) contained within an object.

which means that if more than one value type is contained within an object they can be unboxed using the below syntax:

```
int a= (int) o; //assigns a to 10
char b= (char) o; // assigns b to 'b'
```

How to implement such object which supports multiple unboxing?

Comment: could you give an example (maybe in pseudo code) what you would like to do?

Comment: There's no such concept as "more than one value type contained within an object" if the object is a boxed value.

Comment: That code will throw an `InvalidCastException` if you assign either an int or a char to `o`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks...Can you copy your comments in the answer, so that I can accept it. So nice of you...

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx)? Has nothing to do with boxing, but sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about casting? In .NET if you have a boxed type it has a specific type and you can only cast it to the actual value type to unbox:

```
object o=10;               // o is a boxed int with value 10
var a=(int)o;              // works
//var b=(byte)o;           // ERROR, this is not what's contained in it
var b=(byte)(int)o;        // works, you get the int out then cast it to byte
var b=Convert.ToByte(o);   // also works, using IConvertible
```

However, the main purpose of generics (initially at least) was to avoid boxing value types at all because of the performance costs involved. You can change most instances of `object` to generic values and preserve the types, and when you use them you'll have the proper value type right away.

Comment: I guess I know that already...The answer to my question is either yes or no. If yes then implement it.

Comment: I disagree, the answer to your question is a puzzled expression. We're all trying to guess what you really mean, but if this isn't it and you really think you can somehow hold two objects at the same time in a handle, then the answer is "no".

Comment: My question is pretty straight forward. It's just "Can you unbox an object o to more than one value type?".

Comment: No, you can only unbox a value to the type it contains. That's the very first thing I said in my answer.

Comment: Yes but my doubt was whether an object can contain more than one value type. As per "clr via c#" value types are stored in the object as data fields. That made me think that why not more than one data field?? If you can answer that, it will be very helpful.

Comment: You... can have multiple fields in an object, sure..? If it's a book you're reading, I suggest you start it over, taking it a lot slower. You have *a lot* of misinformation that you keep building on. You're getting multiple answers telling you the same thing and you keep persisting with this unboxing a type as different types thing. A type is a type man, period.

Comment: okay...I read it again and figured out the issue but anyway it was a good experience . It was actually saying that the data fields of value type (struct) are contained in the boxed object and I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 2):

A boxed value can only be the boxed form of a single type - if you call `o.GetType()` you'll find out what that is.

In general, you can only unbox to the exact same type, with a few wrinkles:

- You can unbox an enum value to its underlying integral type, and vice versa
- There's no such thing as a boxed nullable value type - boxing will result in either a boxed form of the non-nullable type, or a null reference. You can unbox *to* a nullable value type, and the result will either be a null value (if the original reference was a null reference) or a non-null value containing the unboxed non-nullable value, if you see what I mean.

So for example:

```
object o = 10;
FileMode mode = (FileMode) o; // Valid conversion to enum

int? n = (int?) o; // n has a value of 10
n = null;
o = n; // o's value is a null reference
n = (int?) o; // n's value is the null int? value
```

Comment: `You can unbox a signed primitive to its equivalent unsigned type (e.g. int/uint) and vice versa`. It throw `InvalidCastException` for me.

Comment: @PetSerAl: You're absolutely right. Oops. Will delete that bit - was getting confused with arrays. (You can cast from `int[]` to `uint[]` and vice versa, via `object`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet What about Avilan's answer. It looks correct to me. Can you please review that one.

Comment: @DeepakMishra: That's a reference type, so will never be boxed. Even if it's a struct, when it's boxed the *original* type will be boxed, so to convert the boxed form to `int` you'd need a double cast - one to unbox, and the other to call the custom conversion.

Comment: Sorry...I had a misconception that converting a reference type to value type is unboxing but according to MSDN: Unboxing is an explicit conversion from the type object to a value type or from an interface type to a value type that implements the interface. I could not find that definition in "CLR via C#". Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom object with for example both an int or a string, you could do this with [explicit conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

Example;

```
public class CustomObject
{
    int Number;
    string Text;

    public CustomObject(int number, string text)  //constructor
    {
        Number = number;
        Text = text;
    }

    public static explicit operator int(CustomObject o)
    {
        return o.Number;
    }

    public static explicit operator string(CustomObject o)
    {
        return o.Text;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VaT52w)

Comment: I really don't think so, you can only unbox to the value type that's contained in the object "box".

Comment: This is a class, therefore it won't be boxed. A cast from `object` won't use the explicit conversion defined by the type. Basically, it answers a different question to the one asked.

Comment: Yes, the terminologies differs. My point was to give an example on how to implement the requested usability described in the question.

Comment: The request uses `object` and unboxing though - and your answer doesn't meet those requirements at all.

Comment: Yes, I had a misconceptions that converting a reference type to value type is called unboxing, but I realized that's scoped to only system.Object reference type. If you see the definition which I provided, it says that value types are data fields contained within an object. If that's true why can't we have more than one data field in an object?